# CORS Challenges: Fetch POST API with vercel, working fine on old laptop despite same vercel configuration

Tags: debugging, cors, nuxt.js, fetch, vercel

I'm currently working on a Nuxt 3 project where I've implemented Fetch APIs to retrieve and send data to my local Vercel project. I recently upgraded to a new HP Victus laptop from my old HP Pavilion. However, I've encountered an issue not only in my Nuxt project, which uses $fetch, but also in a simple HTML setup using the Fetch API.

The problem arises when I use a POST API request to send data to my local Vercel project. It gives the following error:

`Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:4002/api/v1/dummy' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.` 
Interestingly, I didn't face this issue on my old laptop with the exact same code.

Here's a snippet of the HTML code I'm using to illustrate the issue:
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <button id="button">Get Data</button>
    <button id="postButton">Post Data</button>
    <script>
        const button = document.getElementById("button");
        button.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
        function myFunction() {
            const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:4002/api/v1/session/650c584be1fe57cf8be3425d';

            // const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api/data';
            const response = fetch(apiUrl).then(response => {
                if(response.ok){
                    return response.json();
                }
            }).then(data => {
                console.log(data)
            });
        }

        const newButton = document.getElementById("postButton");
        newButton.addEventListener("click", postFunction);
        function postFunction(){
            // const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api/data';
            const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:4002/api/v1/dummy';

            const postData = {
                userId: 1,
                id: 101, // Change to a unique ID
                title: 'Custom Post Title',
                body: 'Custom Post Body',
            };
            fetch(apiUrl, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify(postData),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                })
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
            })
        }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the vercel code:
dummy.ts

```
import type { VercelRequest, VercelResponse } from '@vercel/node';
import { ensureOptionsPreflight } from '../../src/middleware/optionsPreflightMiddleware';
const handler = async (req: VercelRequest, res: VercelResponse) => {
  console.log('req method', req.method);

  switch (req.method) {
    case 'OPTIONS': {
      console.log(req.method);
      return ensureOptionsPreflight(req, res);
    }
    case 'POST': {
      const newRes = req.body;
      console.log('newRes', req.body);
      res.status(200).json(newRes);
      break;
    }
    default: {
      console.log('method not defined');
      res.status(400).json({ status: 'invalid method' });
    }
  }
};
export default handler;
```

and here is the vercel config that i have added:

vercel.json

```
"headers": [
    {
      "source": "/api/(.*)",
      "headers": [
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "value": "true" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "value": "*" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "value": "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "value": "*,X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version" }
      ]
    }
  ],
```

And i have tested the fetch api with node serve as well here is the code for that:
server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: true,
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    allowedHeaders: [
      "Content-Type",
      "Authorization",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    ],
    credentials: true,
  })
);
app.use(express.json());

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

let data = [];

app.post("/api/data", (req, res) => {
  const { body } = req;
  data.push(body);
  console.log("post data", body);
  res.status(201).json(body);
});

app.get("/api/data", (req, res) => {
  console.log("get", res, req);
  res.json(data);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

You can change the apiUrl in html code mentioned above to test out node server.js file. In this the fetch POST is working fine.

I'm not sure what is the issue can you please help me out

I've attempted various steps to troubleshoot this issue, including:

- CORS Configuration: I've double-checked the CORS configuration on my local Vercel project to ensure that it allows requests from the origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500'. The CORS settings appear to be correctly configured.
- Clearing Cache: I cleared the browser cache on my new laptop to rule out any cached configurations causing the problem.
- Browser Extensions: I disabled all browser extensions to make sure they weren't affecting the requests.
- Testing in Multiple Browsers: I tested the issue in different web browsers on my new laptop, but the problem persists across browsers.
- Comparing Environments: I've made a detailed comparison of the software versions and configurations between my old and new laptops. They appear to be consistent, making the source of the issue even more puzzling.

What I was expecting was that my Nuxt 3 project and simple HTML setup should work seamlessly, just as they did on my old HP Pavilion laptop. I expect to resolve the CORS issue, so I can continue developing without hindrances.

Any insights or guidance on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your assistance.